# Is there a way to remove icons from the titlebar under KDE Plasma 5.8?

Tags: arch-linux, kde, window

I just installed KDE with arch linux and I'm trying to remove icons from the titlebar, after looking into the settings and on various websites I didn't manage to find a way. Does anyone know if this is possible?
Thanks

Comment: Haven't touched Neon yet. This was a bit tricky in previous KDE versions. In those versions, to get them out of the panel, you have to first click on the i ching symbol (the three stacked horizontal bars - or, before that, the cashew symbol) to open the panel for modification. Then, when you hover over an icon, a tool tip appears with the option to delete the icon.  Maybe Neon does things in a similar way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System Settings → Application Style → Window Decorations → Buttons.